# .Net Core 2.1 Method not found: MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(System.String)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

net core 2.1 in configure i have the following problem:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(System.String)'.
```

this is the code of startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            //IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            //                                                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            //                                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            //Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

            AutoMapperVmConfig.RegisterMappings();
            AutoMapperDtoConfig.RegisterMappings();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddMvc()
            //    .AddJsonOptions(options =>{
            //            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            //        }
            //    );

            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => (options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true);

            services.AddAutoMapper();

            // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.Configure<ConnectionStringsMyWallet>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStringsMyWallet"));

            services.AddKendo();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            //registrazione dei componenti con Castle Windsor
            var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();

            windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<EfDbUpdateException>());

            windsorContainer.Register(
                Component.For<IUserDataRepository>().ImplementedBy<EfUserDataRepository>().LifestyleTransient().Interceptors<EfDbUpdateException>(),
                Component.For<IPeriodoRepository>().ImplementedBy<EfPeriodoRepository>().LifestyleTransient().Interceptors<EfDbUpdateException>(),
                Component.For<IMovimentiRepository>().ImplementedBy<EfMovimentiRepository>().LifestyleTransient().Interceptors<EfDbUpdateException>(),
                Component.For<IUserSessionProvider>().ImplementedBy<UserSessionValuesInHttpContext>().LifestyleTransient()
            );

            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(windsorContainer, services);

            return serviceProvider;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }         

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I add nuget package Microsoft.Aspnetcore.All and this solves my problem.
But package Microsoft.Aspnetcore.All is too huge.
I search package from dependencies of Microsoft.Aspnetcore.All and find appropriate - **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures**
With this package problem disappeared